# Sort Array of Dictionarys in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting, dictionary

Hello every one I am trying to sort an array([["key": Int, "value": Any]] format) of dictionary by using sorted by in swift but it couldn't work. here is my array with dictionaries, these dictionary contains a dictionary and i have a unique identifier in child dictionary that is "id", and i have unique key as well. Please guide me on this. actually my data below format. how to sort it with "id" get values (["isMale": false, "status": "", "name": "John","id": 10)])

```
var dataArray  = [(key: 10, value: ["isMale": false, "status": "", "name": "John","id": 10)], (key: 2, value: ["isMale": false, "status": "", "name": "John","id": 2]), (key: 3, value: ["isMale": false, "status": "", "name": "John","id": 3]), (key: 7, value:
 ["isMale": false, "status": "", "name": "John","id": 7]), (key: 9, value: ["isMale": false, "status": "", "name": "John","id": 9]), (key: 4, value: ["isMale": false, "status": "", "name": "John","id": 4]), (key: 6, value: ["isMale": false, "status": "", "name": "John","id": 6]), (key: 5, value: ["isMale": false, "status": "", "name": "John","id": 5]), (key: 8, value: ["isMale": false, "status": "", "name": "John","id": 8]), (key: 11, value: ["isMale": false, "status": "", "name": "John","id": 11])];

var data = [Int:Any]() data = dataArray.sorted(by: { $0 < $1 })
```

Comment: What is the logic for the sort? In other words: What define that a particular dict should be at an lower index after the sort agains another dict?

Comment: `let result = dataArray.sorted(by: {($0["key"] as! Int) < ($1["key"] as! Int)})`

Comment: after sorting i want to get all the values

Comment: actually my data in below format: [("key":"A", "value":["isMale": false, "status": "", "name": "John","id": 10]), ("key":"B", "value":["isMale": false, "status": "", "name": "John","id": 2), ("key":"C", "value":["isMale": false, "status": "", "name": "John","id": 3])]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort `dataArray` by value["id"] variable like this:

```
var dataArray  = [
    (key: 10, value: ["isMale": false, "status": "", "name": "John","id": 10]),
    (key: 2, value: ["isMale": false, "status": "", "name": "John","id": 2]),
    (key: 3, value: ["isMale": false, "status": "", "name": "John","id": 3]),
    (key: 7, value: ["isMale": false, "status": "", "name": "John","id": 7]),
    (key: 9, value: ["isMale": false, "status": "", "name": "John","id": 9]),
    (key: 4, value: ["isMale": false, "status": "", "name": "John","id": 4]),
    (key: 6, value: ["isMale": false, "status": "", "name": "John","id": 6]),
    (key: 5, value: ["isMale": false, "status": "", "name": "John","id": 5]),
    (key: 8, value: ["isMale": false, "status": "", "name": "John","id": 8]),
    (key: 11, value: ["isMale": false, "status": "", "name": "John","id": 11])];

let sorted = dataArray.sorted(by: {
    let id0 = $0.value["id"] as! Int
    let id1 = $1.value["id"] as! Int
    return id0 < id1
})

print(sorted.map { $0.key })
```